# Validating the password requested during sign up with AWS Cognito User Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Is there a way to see the password within the Lambda triggers that can be fired off by a sign-up or password change on AWS Cognito User Pool?

I want to get the password and compare it to lists of previously compromised passwords (the haveibeenpwned lists) to ensure password strength at a much higher level than what is possible by the arbitrary complexity rules that can be defeated by garbage like "Password!23"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that it currently is not possible to do as simply as I had hoped.

What you would have to do is to turn on the USER_PASSWORD_AUTH type authentication flow which means the password is sent in the HTTP POST request and setup your own reverse proxy to take the request, check the password details and then forward the request onto Cognito, accept the response and then send it back to the browser.

Or just turn on the "Advanced Security Features" option that they give you and tick the box for checking passwords against compromised lists... which is what I imagine AWS is trying to force you to do.

Comment: Just a comment, I found USER_PASSWORD_AUTH to be used for sign-in not sign-up

Answer (score 0):

I suppose another option you could try is to implement a front-end service to intermediate the password setting/change operation.

For example, you could have something like this:

1. Custom set/change password front-end, pointing to the API gateway below
2. API Gateway to receive the change password request, pointing to the lambda function below
3. Lambda function that will receive the user's new password, pointing to the cognito below.
4. Cognito that will store the user's credentials.

The lambda function implementation would receive the change password HTTPS request, run whatever validation logic you want, and next call the AWS Cognito SDK to change the password through one of the two methods below:

- [ChangePassword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ChangePassword.html)
- [AdminSetUserPassword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminSetUserPassword.html)

Answer (score -3):

If you are using Amazon Cognito than you should not take worry about passwords and its complexity. It is totally managed by Cognito.

Your authentication will be based on Tokens only :)

There is no way to retrieve the password from lambda trigger.

But yes, You can do one thing, Set status to FORCE CHANGE PASSWORD. So that user must have to reset password after first login.

After that, whenever your user try to change password, You can add your own constrains in your UI before calling [ChangePassword API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ChangePassword.html)

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is an incredibly naive approach to simply state that what AWS does is sufficient to ensure good passwords. As I said in my question, even if you turn on every rule that AWS has available, Password1! is still acceptable, as is Letmein123! etc... These are garbage passwords and as per the most recent NIST recommendations, comparing against a list of known compromised passwords is the best known way of ensuring a good password policy.